# How to convert website to selected language in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating website using laravel and client's requirement is that on desktop we have to put language dropdown. Whenever user select any language from dropdown the whole website content should convert to selected language automatically.By Default the website will come in English language (Ex when user select german language from dropdown all content should convert to german language). If anyone know solution than please help.

Comment: There are packages available like this one https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable .

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Start form this point: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

The `$locale` is your language

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
});
```

Good luck!